# Execute shell scripts no access on Jenkins server

Tags: shell, jenkins

When I configure Jenkins server to run some shell scripts. it report such error:

```
Running as SYSTEM
     Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test1        
    [test1] $ /bin/bash /tmp/jenkins2042506957495136817.sh        
    jenkins   
    /usr/bin/python3     
    /tmp/jenkins2042506957495136817.sh: line 10: cd: /root: Permission denied  
    /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test1    
    /tmp/jenkins2042506957495136817.sh: line 14: auto_run.sh: No such file or directory    
    Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure   
    Finished: FAILURE
```

here is my shell scripts on Jenkin projects configuration 
Build --> Execute shell

```sh
#!/bin/bash
whoami
which python3
cd /root
pwd    
source auto_run.sh
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please tell us what you have tried before asking a question. You should be able to look up the error: `/tmp/jenkins2042506957495136817.sh: line 10: cd: /root: Permission denied`. It means you can't access the `/root` directory. I would suggesting moving `/root/auto_run.sh` to a directory without permissions issues, say `/home/YOUR_USERNAME`.

Answer (score 0):

you are running as "jenkins" user which normally doesn't have access to /root folder hence, the error. Also make sure that /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test1/auto_run.sh have execute permission from jenkins user.